# Problems calling my methods, can someone offer some input?

Tags: java

So I've been sitting here for the last 5 hours trying to understand what I'm doing wrong, I have a simple beginners task that is to create multiple different methods to find out a users name which is stored as a global variable, and which month they were born stored as an Integer. Once the Integer has been stored I use a switch statement to correspond to a certain month which I think has went fine so far. However, in calling my methods in my main class I keep getting null value returned for both the UsersName variable and also the monthString variable.

```
public class BirthMonthWithFunctions {

    public static String UsersName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String monthString = null;
        BirthMonthWithFunctions bm = new BirthMonthWithFunctions();
        BirthMonthWithFunctions.getUsersName();
        bm.getUsersBirthMonthNumber();
        BirthMonthWithFunctions.computeBirthMonth(0);
        System.out.print(UsersName + "Was born in: " + monthString);

    }

    static void getUsersName() {
        String UsersName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?");


    }

    public int getUsersBirthMonthNumber() {
        int BirthMonth = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Which month were you born in as an integer between 1-12?"));

        return BirthMonth;
    }

    public static String computeBirthMonth(int BirthMonth) {

        int choice = BirthMonth;
        String monthString;
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: monthString = "January";
                    break;
            case 2: monthString = "February";
                    break;
            case 3: monthString = "March";
                    break;
            case 4: monthString = "April";
                    break;
            case 5: monthString = "May";
                    break;
            case 6: monthString = "June";
                    break;
            case 7: monthString = "July";
                    break;
            case 8: monthString = "August";
                    break;
            case 9: monthString = "September";
                    break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                    break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                    break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                    break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid Month";
                    break;

        }

        return monthString;

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you have a local (mis-named) `UsersName` variable in `getUsersName`--that is not the same `UsersName` as the static one. If you want to set the static one, don't create a local variable of the same name. Unrelated, but Java conventions name variables without an initial capital letter, and getter methods return a value.

Comment: There are too many basic mistakes in your code. You don't return values from methods, you don't assign return values to variables, you use wrong scopes and so on. I'd suggest going through a tutorial of Java basics covering these topics first.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with this piece of code that I've edited.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String monthString = null;
    BirthMonthWithFunctions bm = new BirthMonthWithFunctions();
    BirthMonthWithFunctions.getUsersName();
    int BirthMonth = bm.getUsersBirthMonthNumber();
    BirthMonthWithFunctions.computeBirthMonth(BirthMonth);
    System.out.print(UsersName + "Was born in: " + monthString);

}

static void getUsersName() {
    UsersName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?");
}
```

Also remove the String variable declaration from the method : computeBirthMonth

It should be something like :

```
public static String computeBirthMonth(int BirthMonth) {

    int choice = BirthMonth;
    switch(choice) {..............
    }

    return monthString;
}
```